# Accidentally deleted Main Activity.java in android studio ,how to get back it..?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Please, tell me how to get back `MainActivity.java` or any other way to add it only `MainActivity.java` is missing `activity_main.xml` is present.

Comment: Try googling "Local History" with inellij / android studio. Also, next time, use a version control system like git or svn

Answer (score 8):

You can try following way to get back you deleted file from Android Studio / IntelliJ :

> 1. On the context menu, choose **Local History**, and click **Show History** on the **submenu**
> 2. The local history view for a project or folder shows you everything that you have done during the last few days. In the Action column of the lower part of the dialog box, select the action you want to roll back. In our case, this is the Deleting action. So doing, the upper part of the dialog box shows the tree view of changed files.

See [Using Local History to restore deleted files](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/01/using-local-history-to-restore-deleted-files/) .

Answer (score 3):

Right Click in your package like:
1)java package if you  want java file 
or
2)layout package if you want layout

than select local history ,select show history
than one screen popup than in right site you will see your deleted java or layout file than select that file than again right click......now select revert selection....now successfully you get you required file in your project.